Treatment of bicarbonate versus fixed acids in acid-base regulation by the kidney
My question concerns the differential treatment of bicarbonate versus other buffer anions in human acid-base physiology. In Guyton (2021)'s physiology textbook, we see the following argument:

Because $\ce{HCO3−}$ must react with a secreted $\ce{H+}$ to form $\ce{H2CO3}$ before it can be reabsorbed, 4320 mEq of $\ce{H+}$ must be secreted each day just to reabsorb the filtered $\ce{HCO3−}$. Then, an additional 80 mEq of $\ce{H+}$ must be secreted to rid the body of the nonvolatile acids produced each day for a total of 4400 mEq of $\ce{H+}$ secreted into the tubular fluid each day. (p. 410)

Similar passages can be found in Boron (2017)'s textbook:

(...) $\ce{HCO3−}$ reabsorption does not represent net $\ce{H+}$ excretion into the urine. It merely prevents the loss of the filtered alkali. (p. 823)


In our example, the kidneys secrete 4390 mmol/day of $\ce{H+}$ into the tubule lumen. The kidneys use most of this secreted acid—4320 mmol/day or ~98% of the total—to reclaim filtered $\ce{HCO3−}$. The balance of the total secreted $\ce{H+}$, 70 mmol/day, the kidneys use to generate new $\ce{HCO3−}$. (p. 825)

On the other hand, as tubule cells excrete $\ce{H+}$ into the lumen, some titrate $\ce{HPO4^2-}$ to form $\ce{H2PO4-}$. This is viewed as net acid excretion, instead of reclamation of filtered $\ce{HPO4^2-}$.
Mathematically, the form of the net acid excretion formula expresses this differential treatment:
$\rm NAE = TA + [NH_4^+] - [HCO_3^-]$
Whereas any amount of filtered $\ce{HCO3−}$ contributes negatively to NAE, since TA is defined to be the amount of base necessary to titrate urine back to pH 7.4, the amount of $\ce{HPO4^2-}$ and $\ce{H2PO4-}$ in the initial filtrate do not affect NAE (assuming that pH of the initial filtrate is 7.4). What matters is the additional amount of titration done.
Why the difference? Any amount of $\ce{HPO4^2-}$ filtered would also mean a loss of buffering capacity of blood. Therefore, shouldn't the formula instead be $\rm NAE = [NH_4^+] - [HCO3^-] - [HPO_4^{2-}]$?
One could argue that since urine contains $\ce{H2PO4-}$ as well as $\ce{HPO4^2-}$, and since $\ce{H2PO4-}$ is a Bronsted-Lowry acid, we must account for the effects of both ions. When the two effects precisely neutralize each other, pH should equal 7.4. Acid is excreted only if phosphate is protonated more than the degree of protonation at pH 7.4. Therefore, instead of subtracting $\rm[HPO_4^{2-}]$, we subtract the difference $\rm[HPO_4^{2-}] - [HPO_4^{2-}]_{pH=7.4}$, which equals -TA by definition.
But then why can't this argument be applied to bicarbonate? Shouldn't we subtract the difference $\rm[HCO_3^-] - [HCO_3^-]_{pH=7.4} = [HCO_3^-] - 24$?

Deliberation on this problem over the past few months has led me into a Stewartian rabbit hole. I now think I have an answer, though I can't cite any sources for this specific issue. I will nevertheless try to share my thoughts just in case anybody is still interested.
Short answer
I think Sabyasachi Pramanik has a point. To state it in other words, the key difference is that bicarbonate ion is the conjugate base of a volatile acid, whereas other buffer ions are conjugate bases of nonvolatile acids.
My initial argument went like this: say there is a buffer ion $\ce{A-}$, which is part of a buffer system characterized by the reaction $\ce{HA} \leftrightharpoons \ce{H+} + \ce{A-}$. Titratable acidity reflects not simply $[\ce{A-}]$, but only the difference $-\mathit{\Delta}[\ce{A-}] = -([\ce{A-}] - [\ce{A-}]_{\rm{pH} = 7.4})$. To justify this, one may think of $\ce{HA}$ as an acid and $\ce{A-}$ as a base. Since plasma and urine contain both ions, we should account for the acid-base effects of both ions. When the effects precisely cancel each other out (in physiological terms), pH should equal 7.4. Titratable acidity measures the discrepancy from that base state. From here, I proceeded to object that the same logic could also be applied to bicarbonate.
However, whereas the conjugate acid of $\ce{A-}$, namely $\ce{HA}$, is 'contained' in the solution, the conjugate acid of bicarbonate, namely $\ce{H2CO3}$, cannot be said to be 'contained' in the same way. The species itself exists in minute quantities; the majority degasifies into CO2. So there is no 'acid effect' to counterbalance the 'alkali effect' of bicarbonate. At all pH levels, even at pH 7.4, bicarbonate is exerting a net 'alkali effect' on plasma. This is why we don't subtract $[\ce{HCO3-}]_{\rm{pH}=7.4}$ when calculating NAE.
Stewartian answer
The above discussion is very informal and nonconventional. I did have those ideas vaguely in mind when I first posted the question, but I was having trouble phrasing them in the language of traditional theory. The Stewart view of acid-base physiology helped me see things more clearly.
In Stewart's view, there are three major independent variables that determine the acid-base status of bodily fluids: $P_{\ce{CO2}}$, SID, and ATOT. If some simplifications are made, it can be said that $[\ce{HCO3-}]$ is determined by the balance of $P_{\ce{CO2}}$ and SID, and $[\ce{A-}]$ by SID and ATOT. The difference lies in the fact that whereas SID and ATOT depend on the composition of the solution, $P_{\ce{CO2}}$ does not; its value is given by the composition of atmospheric air and the rate of ventilation.
Although excretion of buffer ions through urine is usually viewed as simply one component of 'acid excretion', from the perspective of Stewart theory it affects both SID and ATOT. Effects on the two variables might as well cancel each other out. However, renal bicarbonate excretion can only affect SID. This is why Stewart argues that sodium bicarbonate is equivalent to NaOH in terms of long-term acid-base balance. The only reason bicarbonate might be preferred is to avoid the immediate effects of high alkalinity. If equilibrium is allowed to be achieved, the two compounds will produce identical effects on acid-base homeostasis. Building upon Stewart's idea, we can predict that any amount of bicarbonate lost through urine is equivalent to a loss of same amounts of NaOH.
To see this, consider a solution containing sodium and a buffer system characterized by the reaction $\ce{HA} \leftrightharpoons \ce{H+} + \ce{A-}$. Suppose it is isolated from the surrounding atmosphere so that bicarbonate and CO2 are absent. Then the pH of this solution will be determined by the Henderson-Hasselbalch equation for the $\ce{HA}$-$\ce{A-}$ buffer system:
$$\textrm{pH} = \textrm{p} K_a + \log_{10} \frac{[\ce{A-}]}{[\ce{HA}]} \ .$$
What would happen if we took out half of all the solutes from the solution? Probably $[\ce{A-}]$ and $[\ce{HA}]$ would both be reduced by half, so their ratio would remain constant. Therefore, pH of the solution would also remain the same.
To analyze this example using Stewart theory, first observe that electroneutrality demands that $[\ce{A-}]$ equals $[\ce{Na+}]$ (ignoring small terms such as H+ or OH-). This is the value of SID in this case. Also, mass conservation dictates that the total mass of $\ce{HA}$ and $\ce{A-}$ remains constant if there is no input or output of materials. This is the value of ATOT in this case. To summarize,
$$[\ce{A-}] = \textrm{SID}, \ [\ce{HA}] = \textrm{A}_{\textrm{TOT}} - \textrm{SID} \ .$$
Consequently, the values of SID and ATOT completely determine the acid-base status of the solution. Informally speaking, SID exerts an alkalinizing influence, since it opens up a charge gap waiting to be filled by anions including OH-. Alternatively, a positive SID can be understood as the 'footprint' of strong alkalis (e. g. Na+ indicates that NaOH has been added). ATOT indicates the presence of weak acids. In this example, taking out half of all the solutes has removed both acid (ATOT) and alkali (SID, as the footprint of NaOH). The two effects have canceled each other out.
On the other hand, consider a sodium bicarbonate solution in equilibrium with a fixed partial pressure of CO2. The pH is given by the Henderson-Hasselbalch equation:
$$\textrm{pH} = \textrm{p} K + \log_{10} \frac{[\ce{HCO3-}]}{s \cdot P_{\ce{CO2}}} \ .$$
Again, electroneutrality demands that $[\ce{HCO3-}] = [\ce{Na+}] = \textrm{SID}$. If SID is halved, $[\ce{HCO3-}]$ would also be halved. However, $P_{\ce{CO2}}$ would remain constant. According to the equation, pH would fall. In this example, taking out half of all the solutes has removed alkali (SID, as the footprint of NaOH) but not acid. Therefore the solution acidifies.
Deriving the NAE equation (without ammonium) from Stewart theory
Armed with this conceptual machinery, let us see if the NAE equation actually makes sense. Ammonium secretion will not be considered, since it seems to involve other issues unrelated to the question at hand.
The hypothetical solutions in the previous section stood for plasma, since the aim was to study how plasma acid-base status changes as a result of urine excretion. Now the focus is on urine, so we shall consider a hypothetical solution that stands for urine. Solutes will be added to, rather than removed from, the solution, in order to represent H+ secretion into the tubule lumen.
Suppose a solution containing strong ions and the $\ce{HA}$-$\ce{A-}$ buffer system is in equilibrium with CO2 gas. Assume that the pH of the solution is 7.4 initially. According to the Henderson-Hasselbalch equation for the $\ce{HA}$-$\ce{A-}$ buffer system,
$$7.4 = \textrm{p} K_a + \log_{10} \frac{[\ce{A-}]_{\textrm{pH} = 7.4}}{\textrm{A}_{\textrm{TOT}} - [\ce{A-}]_{\textrm{pH} = 7.4}} \ .$$
If CO2 were removed and the value of SID were adjusted to $[\ce{A-}]_{\textrm{pH} = 7.4}$, every term of the equation would remain the same. Therefore, the pH of the soultion would again be 7.4. This thought experiment suggests that the size of acidifying effect of the weak acids in the solution can be represented by the quantity $[\ce{A-}]_{\textrm{pH} = 7.4}$, since it is precisely canceled out by an SID of $[\ce{A-}]_{\textrm{pH} = 7.4}$.
Now, suppose that strong acid is added to the solution, as a model of urine acidification. By excreting this solution from the body, we remove alkali by an amount identical to the final SID of the solution. Along with this, we also remove some amount of weak acid. But this quantity has no reason to change compared to the initial state, since only strong acid has been added. Therefore, the amount of acid excreted is $[\ce{A-}]_{\textrm{pH} = 7.4}$, and net acid excretion can be calculated as $[\ce{A-}]_{\textrm{pH} = 7.4} - \textrm{SID}$.
Electroneutrality demands that the following equation approximately holds:
$$\textrm{SID} = [\ce{HCO3-}] + [\ce{A-}] \ .$$
Substituting, we obtain
$$\textrm{NAE} = [\ce{A-}]_{\textrm{pH} = 7.4} - \textrm{SID} = [\ce{A-}]_{\textrm{pH} = 7.4} - [\ce{A-}] - [\ce{HCO3-}] \ .$$
Titratable acidity is defined as $\textrm{TA} = [\ce{A-}]_{\textrm{pH} = 7.4} - [\ce{A-}]$. In conclusion,
$$\textrm{NAE} = \textrm{TA} - [\ce{HCO3-}] \ .$$
(One article has attempted a similar derivation based on Stewart theory, but I think it contains an error. The authors assert that NAE can be understood as equivalent to $\textrm{SID}_{\textrm{pH} = 7.4} - \textrm{SID}$, but according to the calculations presented above, NAE as defined by the authors would differ from the true value by $[\ce{HCO3-}]_{\textrm{pH} = 7.4}$.)
